# how to skip a column while using jsPDF

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

I am trying to export an HTML table to PDF using jsPDF, but I have an overlapping columns issue. I have to skip some columns, but don't know how to do.

Here is my table:

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right m-r-xs" ng-click="toPDF()">PDF çıktısı al</a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right m-r-xs" ng-click="toExcel()">Excel çıktısı al</a>
                <div class="ibox-content" id="table">
                    <table id="archiveTable" class="table table-responsive table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th id="bypassme" class="text-center noExl">Şüpheli</th>
                                <th width="20">No</th>
                                <th>Plaka</th>
                                <th>Ad</th>
                                <th>Plaka Noktası</th>
                                <th>Sahip Türü</th>
                                <th>Tarih</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="clickable" ng-repeat="data in archivedata" ng-click="showArchiveDetails(data)">
                                <td ng-class="{'text-danger': data.dangerous}" class="text-center noExl">
                                    <span ng-if="data.dangerous" tooltip="Şüpheli"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i></span>
                                </td>
                                <td>{{(shownCurrentPage-1)*resultsPerPage + $index + 1}}</td>
                                <td>{{data.plate}}</td>
                                <td>{{people[data.ownerType][data.ownerId].name}}</td>
                                <td>{{data.platePoints.pointName}}</td>
                                <td ng-switch="data.ownerType">
                                    <span ng-switch-when="1">{{labels.resident}}</span>
                                    <strong ng-switch-when="2">{{labels.guest}}</strong>
                                    <span ng-switch-when="3">Tanınmayan</span>
                                    <span ng-switch-when="4">Düzenli Ziyaretçi</span>
                                </td>
                                <td>{{data.lprDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the Javascript code:

```
$scope.toPDF = function(){
    var from = $filter('date')($scope.archive.from,'dd.MM.yyyy HH.mm');
    var to = $filter('date')($scope.archive.to,'dd.MM.yyyy HH.mm');
    var filename = "Arşiv - " + from + " - " + to + ".pdf";

    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    // source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference
    // to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped.
    source = $('#table')[0];

    // we support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style 
    // ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
    // There is no support for any other type of selectors 
    // (class, of compound) at this time.
    specialElementHandlers = {
        // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
        '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
            // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
            return true
        }
    };
    margins = {
        top: 80,
        bottom: 60,
        left: 40,
        width: 522
    };
    // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
    // 'inches' in this case
    pdf.fromHTML(
    source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
    margins.left, // x coord
    margins.top, { // y coord
        'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    },

    function (dispose) {
        // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
        //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
        pdf.save(filename);
    }, margins);
};
```

I want the column named "Şüpheli" is skipped while exporting because there is no text for it to print.

Although for this table it would be better to put a proper text instead of the icon in that column, I still need this ignoring functionality for some columns in another tables as well.

Here what I get for now:
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit what is passed in your source variable before you pass it to fromHTML. It's possible to remove parts based on classnames.

For example:

```
cln_source2 = source.cloneNode(true);
var deleterows = [];
$(cln_source2.childNodes[1].rows).each(function(ri, row){
    var deletecells = [];
    $(row.cells).each(function(ci, cell){
        if( $(cell).hasClass('no_export') )
            deletecells.push(ci);
    });
    $.each(deletecells.reverse(), function(i, ii){
        row.deleteCell(ii);
    });
    if($(row).hasClass('omitted-row'))
            deleterows.push(ri);

});
$.each(deleterows.reverse(), function(i, ii){
    cln_source2.childNodes[1].deleteRow(ii);
});
```

This will remove any items that have a classname of "no_export" or even whole rows using "omitted-row".

Here's a fiddle showing a table being exported with the last column ignored: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c5b1a9wr/)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a method to obtain the data of a table in a JSON with the possibility of ignoring a column. The method is the following.

```
tableToJson(table, ignoreCell = -1) {

        let headers = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < table.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
            if (i !== ignoreCell) headers[i] = $(table.rows[0].cells[i]).text();
        }

        let rows = [];
        for (let i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
            let tableRow = table.rows[i];
            let rowData = {};

            for (let j = 0; j < tableRow.cells.length; j++) {
                if (j !== ignoreCell) rowData[j] = $(tableRow.cells[j]).text();
            }
            rows.push(rowData);
        }

        table = [];
        table['headers'] = headers;
        table['rows'] = rows;

        return table;
    }
```

The method receives as an argument the table, which you can select with jQuery and send it how.

The second one for subway is the number of the column to ignore, if you do not send anything nothing happens, you will not ignore anything

```
let table = $('#table').get(0);
    table = this.tableToJson(table, 5);
```

To access the JSON is, `table.headers` contains the headers and `table.rows` the information of the columns.